# Is there a specified order for abilities on cards, specifically creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was reviewing the a spreadsheet I created of the RTR spoiler to prepare my strategy for this coming weekend. In doing so, I noticed that here and on previous sets if a creature has flying, it is virtually always the first ability listed on the card.

Now, I see a strong parallel between Magic card abilities and [Java class, method, and member modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7398230/330057). In the same vein that a `public static int` is syntactically the same as a `static public int`, a creature that is `flying, deathtouch` is the same as `deathtouch, flying`. But you never really see the latter, only the former.

A search of the official rules didn't indicate anything, nor did Google.

Is there a canonical, conventional, or official order by which I can expect cards to have their abilities listed on the card?

Edit: I take back one comment. Faerie Invaders has Flash before Flying. Perhaps Flash is 'more important' than Flying?

Comment: iirc the ordering is usually: casting modifiers for this spell (flash, additional cost...),  normal abilities, activated abilities, triggered abilities, alternate casting (suspend, cycling, kicker...) ,flavor text.

Comment: Cairn Wanderer is a good place to start for keyword order.

Comment: too much forced the Java mention

Comment: @Zhen It wasn't forced at all. It was the first thing I thought of when I began pondering the ability-order problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has come up in the distant past, so there is no telling whether the design philosophy has changed. In the [June 2006 Ask Wizards](http://wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/askwizards/0606) column,

> Q: I've noticed on creatures with multiple keywords (flying, trample, etc.) that the keywords are in a certain order. For instance, Flying comes before First Strike and First Strike comes before Trample (Just look at Akroma, Angel of Wrath). My question is: Imagine that there was a creature printed with every keyword in Magic, what is the ordering of the keywords and is there any logical pattern to the ordering? --Matthew Burnaby, BC, Canada
>
> A: From Del Laugel, Senior Editor: The short answer is that there's no fixed order for keywords. I check Oracle for similar cards whenever an unusual combination comes up, but my top priority is getting the individual cards to read well. But what fun is a short answer?
>
> [Following is an example card with just about every keyword ever, **Keyword Ultimus**, cut from this answer for brevity]

In a now-disappeared thread from the shut down [wizards community forum](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75842/18985998/Whats_the_order_for_evergreen_keywords?pg=2), a user **magicalblender** supposedly compiled a list of evergreen keywords, and which ones always proceed the other. I cannot verify the correctness of this claim, as I haven't updated my `cards.mwsbase` database with the most recent cards.

Answer (score 5):

From a rules standpoint, the order in which the abilities are written is of no importance. (The exception is spell abilities. They are performed in order. For example, [Footbottom Feast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Footbottom%20Feast) has two spell abilities.)

From a clarity standpoint, placing abilities in a predictable order and placing certain abilities before others makes a difference.

The card designers spend considerable effort making the cards as clear as possible, so they adhere to some form of convention.

I do not know if they publish these conventions, and I'm sure they are fluid (changed as needed).

Comment: Of course. The question is, have they ever posted their guidelines?

Comment: Don't know. You asked if there was. You also brought up the rules. I answered those, and that's all I can answer.

Comment: They often talk about design decision on their blog, and might have published something there, but I doubt they would have published something comprehensive.

Comment: Perhaps this is best asked on Maro's tumblr. :-)

Comment: Flash is important to know when in hand. That might be why it's first.

Comment: The order of one-word abilities appears constant, and it's not [alphabetical](http://magiccards.info/dvd/en/1.html).

Comment: They have answered the question about how they decide the [order of the color symbols](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtgcom/askwizards/0604), but i'm not aware of an answer about ability order. I will point out that the order *is* important for linked abilities…

Comment: @ghoppe, No, it doesn't matter for linked abilities, though they will always be ordered such that the one that references the other will be second.

Comment: @ghoppe, 607.2a (for example) uses the words "the first ability" and "the second ability", but they mean the "ability matching the first description" and the "ability matching the second description". They might not be the first and second on the card. For example, the first and third ability of [mtg:Dance of Many] are linked.

Comment: @ikegami Counterpoints: [Epic Experiment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253552) and [Primitive Etchings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46465). Also, [Footbottom Feast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247300) would work quite a bit differently if the abilities were listed in a different order.

Comment: @ghoppe, uh, the first two only have one ability. you're right about Footbottom Feast, though. I'll adjust accordingly in a few.

Comment: @ikegami nope. Primitive Etchings has a static ability (reveal…) linked to a triggered ability (whenever…). See CR 603.10 for an example.

Comment: @ghoppe, ok, I'll concede that Primitive Etchings has two abilities. Their order is unimportant, though, as mentioned in my first two comments two you. Epic Experiment still has one, though. It has a *spell ability* (whose *instructions* are performed in the order written). Even if you consider it to be three spell abilities, that's already covered in the earlier update.

Comment: *112.2c An object may have multiple abilities. If the object is represented by a card, then aside from certain defined abilities that may be strung together on a single line (see rule 702, “Keyword Abilities”), each paragraph break in a card’s text marks a separate ability.* What I take from this is also the reverse: If there is no paragraph between non-keyword abilities, they are 1 ability.

Comment: @Hackworth, I thought so to, but ghoppe pointed out a rule that contradicts that induction.

Comment: I think the rules are a little fuzzy in 112.2c. Reading section 112 (especially 112.3), it seems there are a few more exceptions. 112.2c references Keyword Abilities, but I think there are some linked abilities written on one line for emphasis that could have a keyword, but don't. Primitive Etchings could be “Anticipate a creature – draw a card. (*Reveal the first card you draw each turn, whenever you reveal a creature card this way, draw a card.*)”

Comment: @ghoppe, Ancitipate would be defined as follows: <<Anticipate is a keyword that represents two abilities. The first is a static ability. The second is a triggered ability. "Anticipate [subtype]" means "..." and "Whenever ...".>> See Madness for an example. Clearly two abilities. And clearly, the order doesn't matter.